# Grails Url shortener plugin not getting installed

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0, url-shortener

I am trying to add a new plugin [mentioned here](http://grails.org/plugin/url-shortener) in my app but it is not been resolved and giving me a error i.e.

```
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.grails.plugins#url-shortener;0.2.1
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#url-shortener;0.2.1!url-shortener.zip:
      ...
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /opt/grails/lib/org.grails.plugins/url-shortener/ivy-0.2.1.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#url-shortener;0.2.1!url-shortener.zip:
      /opt/grails/lib/org.grails.plugins/url-shortener/jars/url-shortener-0.2.1.zip
      /opt/grails/lib/org.grails.plugins/url-shortener/bundles/url-shortener-0.2.1.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /opt/grails/src/libs/url-shortener-0.2.1.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#url-shortener;0.2.1!url-shortener.zip:
      /opt/grails/src/libs/url-shortener-0.2.1.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /opt/grails/dist/url-shortener-0.2.1.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#url-shortener;0.2.1!url-shortener.zip:
      /opt/grails/dist/url-shortener-0.2.1.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/dhanendra-jft/.grails/2.2.0/cached-installed-plugins/url-shortener-0.2.1.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#url-shortener;0.2.1!url-shortener.zip:
      /home/dhanendra-jft/.grails/2.2.0/cached-installed-plugins/url-shortener-0.2.1.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /opt/grails/plugins/url-shortener-0.2.1.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#url-shortener;0.2.1!url-shortener.zip:
      /opt/grails/plugins/url-shortener-0.2.1.zip
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-url-shortener/tags/RELEASE_0.2.1/url-shortener-0.2.1.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#url-shortener;0.2.1!url-shortener.zip:
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-url-shortener/tags/RELEASE_0.2.1/grails-url-shortener-0.2.1.zip
    ==== localMavenResolver: tried
      /home/dhanendra-jft/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/url-shortener/0.2.1/url-shortener-0.2.1.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#url-shortener;0.2.1!url-shortener.zip:
      /home/dhanendra-jft/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/url-shortener/0.2.1/url-shortener-0.2.1.zip
    ==== mavenCentral: tried
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/url-shortener/0.2.1/url-shortener-0.2.1.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#url-shortener;0.2.1!url-shortener.zip:
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/url-shortener/0.2.1/url-shortener-0.2.1.zip
    ==== http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org: tried
      http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/url-shortener/0.2.1/url-shortener-0.2.1.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#url-shortener;0.2.1!url-shortener.zip:
      http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/url-shortener/0.2.1/url-shortener-0.2.1.zip
    ==== http://repository.codehaus.org: tried
      http://repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/url-shortener/0.2.1/url-shortener-0.2.1.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#url-shortener;0.2.1!url-shortener.zip:
      http://repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/url-shortener/0.2.1/url-shortener-0.2.1.zip
    ==== http://download.java.net/maven/2/: tried
      http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/grails/plugins/url-shortener/0.2.1/url-shortener-0.2.1.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#url-shortener;0.2.1!url-shortener.zip:
      http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/grails/plugins/url-shortener/0.2.1/url-shortener-0.2.1.zip
    ==== http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/: tried
      http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/org/grails/plugins/url-shortener/0.2.1/url-shortener-0.2.1.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#url-shortener;0.2.1!url-shortener.zip:
      http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/org/grails/plugins/url-shortener/0.2.1/url-shortener-0.2.1.zip
    ==== http://www.arquetipos.co.cr/blog/files/grails-image-tools-1.0.4.zip: tried
      http://www.arquetipos.co.cr/blog/files/grails-image-tools-1.0.4.zip/org/grails/plugins/url-shortener/0.2.1/url-shortener-0.2.1.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#url-shortener;0.2.1!url-shortener.zip:
      http://www.arquetipos.co.cr/blog/files/grails-image-tools-1.0.4.zip/org/grails/plugins/url-shortener/0.2.1/url-shortener-0.2.1.zip
    ==== http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/paypal/sdk/permissionssdk/2.3.106/: tried
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/paypal/sdk/permissionssdk/2.3.106/org/grails/plugins/url-shortener/0.2.1/url-shortener-0.2.1.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#url-shortener;0.2.1!url-shortener.zip:
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/paypal/sdk/permissionssdk/2.3.106/org/grails/plugins/url-shortener/0.2.1/url-shortener-0.2.1.zip
    ==== http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/paypal/sdk/merchantsdk/2.5.106/: tried
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/paypal/sdk/merchantsdk/2.5.106/org/grails/plugins/url-shortener/0.2.1/url-shortener-0.2.1.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#url-shortener;0.2.1!url-shortener.zip:
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/paypal/sdk/merchantsdk/2.5.106/org/grails/plugins/url-shortener/0.2.1/url-shortener-0.2.1.zip
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        :: org.grails.plugins#url-shortener;0.2.1: not found
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Documentation of the plugin is [here](https://github.com/kaleidos/grails-url-shortener)

I am currently using grails 2.2.0 and as per mentioned the plugin is available for this version of grails.

i have tried adding this dependency in BuildConfig.groovy in plugin block and tried in dependencies as well.

Comment: I ran into the same issue, see the solution that worked for us here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28836824/311525

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default grails repo provided in 2.2 or smaller does not work now. We fixed this issue by adding the following line to the grails.project.dependency.resolution closure in the BuildConfig.groovy file:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {

repositories {

      ********

    mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/"

      ********
}
}
```

*duplicate answer of [Scott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836824/grails-2-2-x-unresolved-dependencies-without-any-changes-to-previously-working-b)