# Grails unable to install plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, spring-webflow

I am trying to install webflow plugin version with my grails 1.3.9 version.

I have tried the following thing.,

1. Using command `grails intall-plugin webflow 1.3.8`
   Result was : `org.grails#grails-webflow;1.3.8: not found`
2. Modifying buildConfig file and adding the line

   plugins {
               compile ":webflow:1.3.8"

When running app result was:

```
UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES
org.grails.plugins#webflow;1.3.8: not found
```

I don't know what else to try. Please help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The repository changed and it's causing problem for older Grails versions.

See my answer at: [Grails Url shortener plugin not getting installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28698371/grails-url-shortener-plugin-not-getting-installed/28699638#28699638) :

> Please use
>
> ```
> mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"
> ```
>
> As a repository definition.

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-central-repo-seemingly-missing-plugin-versions-td4658720.html

Comment: Its not working for Spring security plugin. Dependencies are still not resolved for Spring security plugin.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. I was getting the error for Shiro plugin and adding this solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue when installing dependencies.

I also changed the maven repo URL in Build.config file as nolonger rails repos available. However, due to my JDK being 1.6 it also failed as it is not support TLS1.2 out of the box.

```
repositories {
        grailsCentral()
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/artifactory/plugins/"

}
```

Hence used a reverse proxy to point to the grails repo as mentioned in the below stack overflow thread.

[How to use TLS 1.2 in Java 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364100/how-to-use-tls-1-2-in-java-6)