# Grails command line cannot download plugins, I can access these plugin zip from my IE

Tags: grails, plugins, download

I am new to Grails and the version Iam using is grails 2.2.4 and jdk 7.

I have successfully create my first app and ran few tests. Now I am trying to download joda-time:1.4 plugin.

I have verified this plugin is available  http://grails.org/plugins/grails-joda-time/tags/RELEASE_1.4/grails-joda-time-1.4.zip and if I click this link I can download the file manually through IE, so firewall is not an issue.

When run refresh dependencies from command prompt I get his following error:

```
    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Development\grails-2.2.4/plugins/joda-time-1.4.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#joda-time;1.4!joda-time.zip:

      C:\Development\grails-2.2.4/plugins/joda-time-1.4.zip

    ==== grailsCentral: tried

      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-joda-time/tags/RELEASE_1.4/joda-time-1.4.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#joda-time;1.4!joda-time.zip:

      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-joda-time/tags/RELEASE_1.4/grails-joda-time-1.4.zip

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            :: org.grails.plugins#joda-time;1.4: not found

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


     | Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn'    
   in      BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

  - org.grails.plugins:joda-time:1.4
```

I have tried setting a proxy and it didn't work. The only other I know is to download the zip manually and install the plugin. I would like grails to automatically download the plugin, please let me know what I am missing here. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grails unable to install plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715832/grails-unable-to-install-plugin)

Comment: and if its not the wrong repo, could you please check, that you are not behind a proxy etc, that works fine with IE but not with your grails setup?

Comment: I searched the stackoverflow for 2 days and finally the first answer here helped me with my issue. thanks cfrick.