# Installation issues for grails activiti plugin with grails 2.2.4

Tags: grails, plugins, dependencies, activiti

I have been trying to install grails activiti plugin in my grails project which uses grails 2.2.4

Repo -

mavenRepo "https://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/"

Dependency -

compile ":activiti:5.12.1"

Running grails refresh-dependencies throws "Unresolved dependencies" error

However if i try the same with grails 2.3.4, the plugin installs properly.

I am not able to figure out the reason behind this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grails unable to install plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715832/grails-unable-to-install-plugin)

Comment: No this isn't, this has to do with grails dependency resolver shipped with grails 2.2 which is different from grails 2.3