# Can't install Grails remote-control plugin

Tags: grails

I added `compile ":remote-control:1.5"` to my BuildConfig.groovy and ran `grails refresh-dependencies`.  It failed to resolve with "module not found: org.grails.plugins#remote-control;1.5" even though the URLs it was trying actually do download the POM and ZIP successfully when accessed via browser.

It broke whether I used `install-plugin` or touched BuildConfig.groovy and ran `refresh-dependencies`.  Plugin manager in Eclipse failed too.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: proxy etc?  or possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715832/grails-unable-to-install-plugin ?

Comment: Yes, this is a dup.  Adding `mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"` fixed it.  Wondering why I never had this problem before but glad it's working now.

Comment: with the recent changes in pivotal and codehaus there are changes with the domains etc.