# Failed to resolve dependencies during grails plugins installation

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I deleted my .grails folder from my PC and when I opened an application in Intellij IDE, the plugins mentioned in buildConfig.groovy start installing. A few plugins were installed but six plugins were unable to install. The following error occurred.

```
 "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java" -Dgrails.home=C:\grails-2.1.1 -Dbase.dir=F:\Projects\sms-sender "-Dtools.jar=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\lib\tools.jar" -Dgroovy.starter.conf=C:\grails-2.1.1/conf/groovy-starter.conf -Xmx768M -Xms768M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -Djline.WindowsTerminal.directConsole=false -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\grails-2.1.1\lib\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy-all\jars\groovy-all-1.8.8.jar;C:\grails-2.1.1\dist\grails-bootstrap-2.1.1.jar org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner --conf C:\grails-2.1.1/conf/groovy-starter.conf idea-print-project-settings
| Loading Grails 2.1.1
| Configuring classpath
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.grails.plugins#shiro;1.1.4

    ==== grailsPlugins: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#shiro;1.1.4!shiro.zip:

      F:\Projects\sms-sender/lib/shiro-1.1.4.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\hibernate-2.1.1/lib/shiro-1.1.4.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\jquery-1.8.0/lib/shiro-1.1.4.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\resources-1.1.6/lib/shiro-1.1.4.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\tomcat-2.1.1/lib/shiro-1.1.4.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\webxml-1.4.1/lib/shiro-1.1.4.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/shiro/ivy-1.1.4.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#shiro;1.1.4!shiro.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/shiro/jars/shiro-1.1.4.zip

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/shiro/bundles/shiro-1.1.4.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/cookie-0.51.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1\dist/cookie-0.51.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.51!cookie.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1\dist/cookie-0.51.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.grails.plugins#shiro;1.1.4: not found

        :: org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.51: not found

        :: org.grails.plugins#executor;0.3: not found

        :: org.grails.plugins#export;1.6: not found

        :: org.grails.plugins#cxf;1.1.1: not found

        :: org.grails.plugins#audit-logging;1.0.1: not found

        :: org.grails.plugins#twitter-bootstrap;3.0.3: not found

        :: org.grails.plugins#quartz;1.0.1: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.grails.plugins#shiro;1.1.4

    ==== grailsPlugins: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#shiro;1.1.4!shiro.zip:

      F:\Projects\sms-sender/lib/shiro-1.1.4.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\hibernate-2.1.1/lib/shiro-1.1.4.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\jquery-1.8.0/lib/shiro-1.1.4.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\resources-1.1.6/lib/shiro-1.1.4.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\tomcat-2.1.1/lib/shiro-1.1.4.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\webxml-1.4.1/lib/shiro-1.1.4.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/shiro/ivy-1.1.4.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#shiro;1.1.4!shiro.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/shiro/jars/shiro-1.1.4.zip

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/shiro/bundles/shiro-1.1.4.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/shiro-1.1.4.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#shiro;1.1.4!shiro.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/shiro-1.1.4.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1\dist/shiro-1.1.4.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#shiro;1.1.4!shiro.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1\dist/shiro-1.1.4.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/shiro-1.1.4.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#shiro;1.1.4!shiro.zip:

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/shiro-1.1.4.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#shiro;1.1.4!shiro.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1/plugins/shiro-1.1.4.zip

    ==== grailsCentral: tried

      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-shiro/tags/RELEASE_1.1.4/shiro-1.1.4.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#shiro;1.1.4!shiro.zip:

      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-shiro/tags/RELEASE_1.1.4/grails-shiro-1.1.4.zip

    ==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/shiro/1.1.4/shiro-1.1.4.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#shiro;1.1.4!shiro.zip:

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/shiro/1.1.4/shiro-1.1.4.zip

    ==== localMavenResolver: tried

      C:\Users\Sikander/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/shiro/1.1.4/shiro-1.1.4.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#shiro;1.1.4!shiro.zip:

      C:\Users\Sikander/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/shiro/1.1.4/shiro-1.1.4.zip

    ==== mavenCentral: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/shiro/1.1.4/shiro-1.1.4.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#shiro;1.1.4!shiro.zip:

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/shiro/1.1.4/shiro-1.1.4.zip

        module not found: org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.51

    ==== grailsPlugins: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.51!cookie.zip:

      F:\Projects\sms-sender/lib/cookie-0.51.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\hibernate-2.1.1/lib/cookie-0.51.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\jquery-1.8.0/lib/cookie-0.51.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\resources-1.1.6/lib/cookie-0.51.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\tomcat-2.1.1/lib/cookie-0.51.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\webxml-1.4.1/lib/cookie-0.51.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/cookie/ivy-0.51.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.51!cookie.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/cookie/jars/cookie-0.51.zip

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/cookie/bundles/cookie-0.51.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/cookie-0.51.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.51!cookie.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/cookie-0.51.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1\dist/cookie-0.51.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.51!cookie.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1\dist/cookie-0.51.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/cookie-0.51.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.51!cookie.zip:

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/cookie-0.51.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.51!cookie.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1/plugins/cookie-0.51.zip

    ==== grailsCentral: tried

      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-cookie/tags/RELEASE_0.51/cookie-0.51.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.51!cookie.zip:

      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-cookie/tags/RELEASE_0.51/grails-cookie-0.51.zip

    ==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/cookie/0.51/cookie-0.51.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.51!cookie.zip:

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/cookie/0.51/cookie-0.51.zip

    ==== localMavenResolver: tried

      C:\Users\Sikander/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/cookie/0.51/cookie-0.51.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.51!cookie.zip:

      C:\Users\Sikander/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/cookie/0.51/cookie-0.51.zip

    ==== mavenCentral: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/cookie/0.51/cookie-0.51.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.51!cookie.zip:

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/cookie/0.51/cookie-0.51.zip

        module not found: org.grails.plugins#executor;0.3

    ==== grailsPlugins: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#executor;0.3!executor.zip:

      F:\Projects\sms-sender/lib/executor-0.3.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\hibernate-2.1.1/lib/executor-0.3.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\jquery-1.8.0/lib/executor-0.3.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\resources-1.1.6/lib/executor-0.3.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\tomcat-2.1.1/lib/executor-0.3.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\webxml-1.4.1/lib/executor-0.3.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/executor/ivy-0.3.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#executor;0.3!executor.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/executor/jars/executor-0.3.zip

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/executor/bundles/executor-0.3.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/executor-0.3.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#executor;0.3!executor.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/executor-0.3.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1\dist/executor-0.3.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#executor;0.3!executor.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1\dist/executor-0.3.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/executor-0.3.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#executor;0.3!executor.zip:

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/executor-0.3.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#executor;0.3!executor.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1/plugins/executor-0.3.zip

    ==== grailsCentral: tried

      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-executor/tags/RELEASE_0.3/executor-0.3.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#executor;0.3!executor.zip:

      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-executor/tags/RELEASE_0.3/grails-executor-0.3.zip

    ==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/executor/0.3/executor-0.3.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#executor;0.3!executor.zip:

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/executor/0.3/executor-0.3.zip

    ==== localMavenResolver: tried

      C:\Users\Sikander/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/executor/0.3/executor-0.3.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#executor;0.3!executor.zip:

      C:\Users\Sikander/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/executor/0.3/executor-0.3.zip

    ==== mavenCentral: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/executor/0.3/executor-0.3.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#executor;0.3!executor.zip:

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/executor/0.3/executor-0.3.zip

        module not found: org.grails.plugins#export;1.6

    ==== grailsPlugins: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.6!export.zip:

      F:\Projects\sms-sender/lib/export-1.6.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\hibernate-2.1.1/lib/export-1.6.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\jquery-1.8.0/lib/export-1.6.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\resources-1.1.6/lib/export-1.6.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\tomcat-2.1.1/lib/export-1.6.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\webxml-1.4.1/lib/export-1.6.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/export/ivy-1.6.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.6!export.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/export/jars/export-1.6.zip

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/export/bundles/export-1.6.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/export-1.6.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.6!export.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/export-1.6.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1\dist/export-1.6.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.6!export.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1\dist/export-1.6.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/export-1.6.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.6!export.zip:

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/export-1.6.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.6!export.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1/plugins/export-1.6.zip

    ==== grailsCentral: tried

      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-export/tags/RELEASE_1.6/export-1.6.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.6!export.zip:

      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-export/tags/RELEASE_1.6/grails-export-1.6.zip

    ==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/export/1.6/export-1.6.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.6!export.zip:

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/export/1.6/export-1.6.zip

    ==== localMavenResolver: tried

      C:\Users\Sikander/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/export/1.6/export-1.6.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.6!export.zip:

      C:\Users\Sikander/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/export/1.6/export-1.6.zip

    ==== mavenCentral: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/export/1.6/export-1.6.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#export;1.6!export.zip:

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/export/1.6/export-1.6.zip

        module not found: org.grails.plugins#cxf;1.1.1

    ==== grailsPlugins: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#cxf;1.1.1!cxf.zip:

      F:\Projects\sms-sender/lib/cxf-1.1.1.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\hibernate-2.1.1/lib/cxf-1.1.1.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\jquery-1.8.0/lib/cxf-1.1.1.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\resources-1.1.6/lib/cxf-1.1.1.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\tomcat-2.1.1/lib/cxf-1.1.1.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\webxml-1.4.1/lib/cxf-1.1.1.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/cxf/ivy-1.1.1.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#cxf;1.1.1!cxf.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/cxf/jars/cxf-1.1.1.zip

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/cxf/bundles/cxf-1.1.1.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/cxf-1.1.1.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#cxf;1.1.1!cxf.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/cxf-1.1.1.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1\dist/cxf-1.1.1.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#cxf;1.1.1!cxf.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1\dist/cxf-1.1.1.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/cxf-1.1.1.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#cxf;1.1.1!cxf.zip:

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/cxf-1.1.1.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#cxf;1.1.1!cxf.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1/plugins/cxf-1.1.1.zip

    ==== grailsCentral: tried

      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-cxf/tags/RELEASE_1.1.1/cxf-1.1.1.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#cxf;1.1.1!cxf.zip:

      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-cxf/tags/RELEASE_1.1.1/grails-cxf-1.1.1.zip

    ==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/cxf/1.1.1/cxf-1.1.1.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#cxf;1.1.1!cxf.zip:

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/cxf/1.1.1/cxf-1.1.1.zip

    ==== localMavenResolver: tried

      C:\Users\Sikander/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/cxf/1.1.1/cxf-1.1.1.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#cxf;1.1.1!cxf.zip:

      C:\Users\Sikander/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/cxf/1.1.1/cxf-1.1.1.zip

    ==== mavenCentral: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/cxf/1.1.1/cxf-1.1.1.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#cxf;1.1.1!cxf.zip:

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/cxf/1.1.1/cxf-1.1.1.zip

        module not found: org.grails.plugins#audit-logging;1.0.1

    ==== grailsPlugins: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#audit-logging;1.0.1!audit-logging.zip:

      F:\Projects\sms-sender/lib/audit-logging-1.0.1.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\hibernate-2.1.1/lib/audit-logging-1.0.1.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\jquery-1.8.0/lib/audit-logging-1.0.1.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\resources-1.1.6/lib/audit-logging-1.0.1.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\tomcat-2.1.1/lib/audit-logging-1.0.1.zip

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SMSServer\plugins\webxml-1.4.1/lib/audit-logging-1.0.1.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/audit-logging/ivy-1.0.1.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#audit-logging;1.0.1!audit-logging.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/audit-logging/jars/audit-logging-1.0.1.zip

      C:\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/audit-logging/bundles/audit-logging-1.0.1.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/audit-logging-1.0.1.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#audit-logging;1.0.1!audit-logging.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/audit-logging-1.0.1.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-2.1.1\dist/audit-logging-1.0.1.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#audit-logging;1.0.1!audit-logging.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1\dist/audit-logging-1.0.1.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/audit-logging-1.0.1.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#audit-logging;1.0.1!audit-logging.zip:

      C:\Users\Sikander\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/audit-logging-1.0.1.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#audit-logging;1.0.1!audit-logging.zip:

      C:\grails-2.1.1/plugins/audit-logging-1.0.1.zip

    ==== grailsCentral: tried

      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-audit-logging/tags/RELEASE_1.0.1/audit-logging-1.0.1.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#audit-logging;1.0.1!audit-logging.zip:

      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-audit-logging/tags/RELEASE_1.0.1/grails-audit-logging-1.0.1.zip

    ==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/audit-logging/1.0.1/audit-logging-1.0.1.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#audit-logging;1.0.1!audit-logging.zip:

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/audit-logging/1.0.1/audit-logging-1.0.1.zip

    ==== localMavenResolver: tried

      C:\Users\Sikander/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/audit-logging/1.0.1/audit-logging-1.0.1.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#audit-logging;1.0.1!audit-logging.zip:

      C:\Users\Sikander/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/audit-logging/1.0.1/audit-logging-1.0.1.zip

    ==== mavenCentral: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/audit-logging/1.0.1/audit-logging-1.0.1.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#audit-logging;1.0.1!audit-logging.zip:

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/audit-logging/1.0.1/audit-logging-1.0.1.zip

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.grails.plugins#shiro;1.1.4: not found

        :: org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.51: not found

        :: org.grails.plugins#executor;0.3: not found

        :: org.grails.plugins#export;1.6: not found

        :: org.grails.plugins#cxf;1.1.1: not found

        :: org.grails.plugins#audit-logging;1.0.1: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.grails.plugins:shiro:1.1.4
- org.grails.plugins:cookie:0.51
- org.grails.plugins:executor:0.3
- org.grails.plugins:export:1.6
- org.grails.plugins:cxf:1.1.1
- org.grails.plugins:audit-logging:1.0.1
```

My buildConfig.groovy looks like this,

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5"
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}.war"

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    inherits("global") {
    }
    log "warn"
    checksums true

    repositories {
        inherits true

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        runtime 'net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.2.6'

    }

    plugins {

        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.8.0"
        runtime ":resources:1.1.6"
        runtime ":twitter-bootstrap:3.0.3"
        build   ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
        compile ":shiro:1.1.4"
        compile ':cookie:0.51'
        runtime ":database-migration:1.1"
        compile ':cache:1.0.0'
        compile ":executor:0.3"
        compile ":export:1.6"
        compile ":cxf:1.1.1"
       //compile ":quartz:1.0.1"
        compile ":audit-logging:1.0.1"

    }
}
```

When I comment out these six failed plugins, settings synchronization works but failed when un-comment them.

Any help would be appreciated. I tried application clean as well and my internet connection is working fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grails unable to install plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715832/grails-unable-to-install-plugin)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Current Maven files are not found from these repositories.
I have also faced this issue and resolved by adding in repositories

> grailsRepo "https://grails.org/plugins"

```
repositories {
        inherits true

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        grailsRepo "https://grails.org/plugins" 
    }
```

Comment: If that doesn't work try this instead.  mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/"

Comment: I tried what @JoshMetcalfe proposed and after adding the protocol in the URL, it worked like a charm:
mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo".

Comment: This repo still works wit  a legacy Grails 2.3.7 project and its old dependencies as of September 2017. :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh your dependencies:

1. Run "grails clean"
2. Run "grails refresh-dependencies"

Answer (score 0):

```
repositories {

    inherits true
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/"
}
```