# Refresh dependencies is terminating... while configuring class path is loading

Tags: grails

[image]*

I have imported code from git and configured everything but upon update dependencies following are the errors*

**marker logs are**

1. The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for groovy.lang.GroovyObject. Fix the build path then try building this project.
2. The type groovy.lang.GroovyObject cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

**following are error logs**

```
!ENTRY org.grails.ide.eclipse.core 4 4 2015-05-25 16:13:03.513
!MESSAGE Command terminated with an exception: org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.client.GrailsProcessDiedException: Grails process died (see details for partial output)
!STACK 0
org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.client.GrailsProcessDiedException: Grails process died
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.client.LineReader.readLineHelp(LineReader.java:133)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.client.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:56)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.client.GrailsClient.getCommandResult(GrailsClient.java:441)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.client.GrailsClient.executeCommand(GrailsClient.java:373)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.client.GrailsCommandExecution.execute(GrailsCommandExecution.java:85)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.LongRunningProcessGrailsExecutor.synchExec(LongRunningProcessGrailsExecutor.java:82)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.commands.GrailsCommand.synchExec(GrailsCommand.java:171)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.commands.GrailsCommandUtils.refreshDependencies(GrailsCommandUtils.java:352)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.core.internal.classpath.GrailsClasspathContainerUpdateJob.runInWorkspace(GrailsClasspathContainerUpdateJob.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.grails.ide.eclipse.core 4 0 2015-05-25 16:13:03.513
!MESSAGE ------System.out:-----------
 Loading Grails 2.2.4
| Configuring classpath
| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):
- org.grails.plugins:jquery:1.7.1
- org.grails.plugins:resources:1.1.6
- org.grails.plugins:export:1.5
- org.grails.plugins:mail:1.0.1
- org.grails.plugins:apns:1.0
- org.grails.plugins:quartz:1.0-RC9
- org.grails.plugins:modalbox:0.4

!SUBENTRY 1 org.grails.ide.eclipse.core 4 0 2015-05-25 16:13:03.513
!MESSAGE ------System.err:-----------
```

**system environments**---->
  ubuntu,jdk 7,grails 2.2.4.

Comment: you tried its own suggestion ?... Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information it sounds like it can''t resolve one of its dependencies.. whats under modalbox:0.4 in your BuildConfig ?

Comment: yes tried by keeping log level to warn,there are warning's for each plugin like module not found. BTW modalbox is not defined in BuildConfig.

Comment: i found solution by following http://stackoverflow.com/a/28873939/4416725