# Grails 1.3.7 plugins not found

Tags: grails

I've seen some similar but there solutions don't seem to work for me.

Trying to run an old Grails 1.3.7 but the plugins can never be located.  If I create even a new Grails 1.3.7 and attempt to install a plugin it fails.  Grails 2.4.3 works fine.

Resolving plugin acegi. Please wait...

```
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.grails.plugins#acegi;0.5.3.2

    ==== grailsPlugins: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#acegi;0.5.3.2!acegi.zip:

      /Users/toddcrone/work/twcrone/grails-1.3.7-test/lib/acegi-0.5.3.2.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      /Users/toddcrone/.gvm/grails/1.3.7/lib/acegi-0.5.3.2.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#acegi;0.5.3.2!acegi.zip:

      /Users/toddcrone/.gvm/grails/1.3.7/lib/acegi-0.5.3.2.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      /Users/toddcrone/.gvm/grails/1.3.7/dist/acegi-0.5.3.2.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#acegi;0.5.3.2!acegi.zip:

      /Users/toddcrone/.gvm/grails/1.3.7/dist/acegi-0.5.3.2.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#acegi;0.5.3.2!acegi.zip:

      /Users/toddcrone/.gvm/grails/1.3.7/plugins/grails-acegi-0.5.3.2.zip

    ==== http://grails.org/plugins: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#acegi;0.5.3.2!acegi.zip:

      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-acegi/tags/RELEASE_0_5_3_2/grails-acegi-0.5.3.2.zip

    ==== mavenCentral: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/acegi/0.5.3.2/acegi-0.5.3.2.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#acegi;0.5.3.2!acegi.zip:

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/acegi/0.5.3.2/acegi-0.5.3.2.zip

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.grails.plugins#acegi;0.5.3.2: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


Error resolving plugin [name:acegi, group:org.grails.plugins, version:0.5.3.2].
Plugin not found for name [acegi] and version [0.5.3.2]
```

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994251/grails-does-not-recognize-any-online-plugin-dependency/28994753#28994753

Comment: Thanks!  My Google-fo is weak.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plugins for Grails 1.3.7 have been moved to http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/. This repo is not in the default `BuildConfig.groovy` list of `repositories`.

In your BuildConfig.groovy:

```
repositories {
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    grailsCentral()

    // add this
    mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/"
}
```

Comment: Cool.  I thought it was something like this.  Been away from Grails a little while.  Going to upvote accept and get other devs to upvote.

Comment: Sorry, not sure why didn't see that earlier answer.  I'm still failing on a couple plugins but they are beta or SNAPSHOT so I'll look harder before I post again.  DOH!