# How to compile grails, vaadin and JPA

Tags: grails, jpa, vaadin

I'm struggling since a week to get the new vaadin treetables version working and I can't resolve the compile dependencies. My grails version is 2.4.2

Here is my BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
grails.server.port.http = 8090
grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}##${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
    }
    log "verbose" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.20'
        runtime 'postgresql:postgresql:9.0-801.jdbc4'

        compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support:3.1.3.RELEASE'

    }

    plugins {       
        build ":tomcat:7.0.54"

        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.16" //":hibernate4:4.3.5.4"
        compile ":gorm-jpa:1.0.0.M1"
        compile ":hibernate-jpa-provider:1.0.0.M1"
        compile ":vaadin:7.3.9"
    }
}
```

And this is the error I get :

```
The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-jpa:jar:1.0.0.RC3, org.grails:grails-datastore-jpa:jar:1.0.0.RC3: Could not find artifact org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-jpa:jar:1.0.0.RC3 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grails unable to install plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715832/grails-unable-to-install-plugin)

Comment: I tried adding the grails secured repo but no success