# Unresolved dependencies in Grails

Tags: grails, dependencies

I just started with Grails and I have this dependence error: I clean the project and I have install in my Ubuntu Ivy, Maven, but error persist.

Somebody have a suggestion??

```
: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        :: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6: configuration not found in commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6: 'master'. It was required from org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2 compile
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Comment: @Salva update the question and paste your BuildConfig.groovy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution guys.

I type this line as a dependency in BuildConfig.groovy and is run ok

```
compile: 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6'
```

Comment: Add the lines around this line to provide some context. And format your answer as code.

Comment: I Add the lines:  dependencies {

  compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6'
  

 }

Comment: Thanks Salva, do have a look at the linked duplicate and let us know if the answer provided there works for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715832/grails-unable-to-install-plugin

Comment: Yeah, the answers is work for me. Thanks