# Grails 2.2.1 and SpringSecurity 1.2.7.3

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am trying to compile a grails 2.2.1 project that uses spring security 1.2.7.3.

```
repositories {

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/"
        mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo"
        mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"

    }

    plugins {
        compile ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        compile ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
        compile ':spring-security-core:1.2.7.3'
        compile ':codenarc:0.18.1'
        compile ':functional-test:1.2.7'
        compile ':selenium:0.8'
        compile ':selenium-rc:1.0.2'
        test ':code-coverage:1.2.5'
}
```

That is my BuildConfig.groovy file.

Now when I run `grails clean` it start to download the plugins as expected but it gets stucked here:

```
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.pom
    tried http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.zip CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.zip http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/: no ivy file nor artifact found for org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core;1.2.7.3
    tried http://repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.pom
    tried http://repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.zip http://repository.codehaus.org: no ivy file nor artifact found for org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core;1.2.7.3
    tried http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.pom http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo: found md file for org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core;1.2.7.3
    => http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.pom (1.2.7.3) downloading http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.pom ...   http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo: downloading http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.pom | Downloading: spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.pom   http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo: downloading http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.pom.sha1 | Downloading: spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.pom.sha1 sha1 OK for http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.pom [SUCCESSFUL ] org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core;1.2.7.3!spring-security-core.pom(pom.original) (527ms)
    tried /home/user/Projects/ellucian_code/banner_student_faculty_grade_entry_app/lib/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.zip
    tried /home/user/.gvm/grails/2.2.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/spring-security-core/jars/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.zip
    tried /home/user/.gvm/grails/2.2.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/spring-security-core/bundles/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.zip
    tried /home/user/.gvm/grails/2.2.1/src/libs/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.zip
    tried /home/user/.gvm/grails/2.2.1/dist/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.zip
    tried /home/user/.grails/2.2.1/cached-installed-plugins/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.zip
    tried /home/user/.gvm/grails/2.2.1/plugins/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.zip
    tried http://grails.org/plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tags/RELEASE_1.2.7.3/grails-spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.zip
    tried http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.zip
    tried http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.zip
    tried http://repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.zip
    tried http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.zip
    tried /home/user/Projects/ellucian_code/banner_student_faculty_grade_entry_app/lib/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.jar
    tried /home/user/.gvm/grails/2.2.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/spring-security-core/jars/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3-sources.jar
    tried /home/user/.gvm/grails/2.2.1/lib/org.grails.plugins/spring-security-core/bundles/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3-sources.jar
    tried /home/user/.gvm/grails/2.2.1/src/libs/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3-sources.jar
    tried /home/user/.gvm/grails/2.2.1/dist/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3-sources.jar
    tried /home/user/.grails/2.2.1/cached-installed-plugins/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3-sources.jar
    tried /home/user/.gvm/grails/2.2.1/plugins/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.jar
    tried http://grails.org/plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tags/RELEASE_1.2.7.3/grails-spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.jar
    tried http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3-sources.jar CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3-sources.jar
    tried http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3-sources.jar CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3-sources.jar
    tried http://repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3-sources.jar
    tried http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3-sources.jar CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3-sources.jar
    tried http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3-sources.jar CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3-sources.jar
```

Now I don't understand why this is happening. A Maven repo should have all the versions of all the plugins that it holds right? So for example, in my case for spring-security-core it should have all the version from 1.0 until whatever the latest is right?

How can I solve this, without manually downloading the file?

EDIT 1: It seems to be downloading it, but then it goes to look for it again.
It is not a duplicate to another question as that question is using a different grails version and I am still getting the issue I mentioned even following what that question said.

EDIT 2: Ok so I deleted my ivy-cache (which I don't know why I should have done this) and run again the `grails clean` command with the new repo, and with `http/https` and this is what I get:

```
| Downloading: antlr-3.2.pom.sha1
sha1 OK for http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr/3.2/antlr-3.2.pom
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.antlr#antlr;3.2!antlr.pom(pom.original) (361ms)
cache: Checking cache for: dependency: org.antlr#antlr-master;3.2 {}
        tried /home/user/Projects/ellucian_code/banner_student_faculty_grade_entry_app/lib/antlr-master-3.2.jar
    grailsPlugins: no ivy file nor artifact found for org.antlr#antlr-master;3.2
        tried /home/user/.gvm/grails/2.2.1/lib/org.antlr/antlr-master/ivy-3.2.xml
        tried /home/user/.gvm/grails/2.2.1/lib/org.antlr/antlr-master/jars/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried /home/user/.gvm/grails/2.2.1/lib/org.antlr/antlr-master/bundles/antlr-master-3.2.jar
    grailsHome: no ivy file nor artifact found for org.antlr#antlr-master;3.2
        tried /home/user/.gvm/grails/2.2.1/src/libs/antlr-master-3.2.xml
        tried /home/user/.gvm/grails/2.2.1/src/libs/antlr-master-3.2.jar
    grailsHome: no ivy file nor artifact found for org.antlr#antlr-master;3.2
        tried /home/user/.gvm/grails/2.2.1/dist/antlr-master-3.2.xml
        tried /home/user/.gvm/grails/2.2.1/dist/antlr-master-3.2.jar
    grailsHome: no ivy file nor artifact found for org.antlr#antlr-master;3.2
        tried /home/user/.grails/2.2.1/cached-installed-plugins/antlr-master-3.2.xml
        tried /home/user/.grails/2.2.1/cached-installed-plugins/antlr-master-3.2.jar
    grailsHome: no ivy file nor artifact found for org.antlr#antlr-master;3.2
don't use cache for org.antlr#antlr-master;3.2: checkModified=true
        tried /home/user/.gvm/grails/2.2.1/plugins/antlr-master-3.2.pom
        tried /home/user/.gvm/grails/2.2.1/plugins/antlr-master-3.2.jar
    grailsHome: no ivy file nor artifact found for org.antlr#antlr-master;3.2
don't use cache for org.antlr#antlr-master;3.2: checkModified=true
        tried http://grails.org/plugins/grails-antlr-master/tags/RELEASE_3.2/antlr-master-3.2.pom
        tried http://grails.org/plugins/grails-antlr-master/tags/RELEASE_3.2/grails-antlr-master-3.2.jar
    grailsCentral: no ivy file nor artifact found for org.antlr#antlr-master;3.2
        tried http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.pom
    mavenCentral: found md file for org.antlr#antlr-master;3.2
        => http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.pom (3.2)
downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.pom ...
    mavenCentral: downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.pom
| Downloading: antlr-master-3.2.pom
    mavenCentral: downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.pom.sha1
| Downloading: antlr-master-3.2.pom.sha1
sha1 OK for http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.pom
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.antlr#antlr-master;3.2!antlr-master.pom(pom.original) (327ms)
        tried /home/user/Projects/ellucian_code/banner_student_faculty_grade_entry_app/lib/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried /home/user/.gvm/grails/2.2.1/lib/org.antlr/antlr-master/jars/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried /home/user/.gvm/grails/2.2.1/lib/org.antlr/antlr-master/bundles/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried /home/user/.gvm/grails/2.2.1/src/libs/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried /home/user/.gvm/grails/2.2.1/dist/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried /home/user/.grails/2.2.1/cached-installed-plugins/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried /home/user/.gvm/grails/2.2.1/plugins/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried http://grails.org/plugins/grails-antlr-master/tags/RELEASE_3.2/grails-antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried http://repository.codehaus.org/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
        tried http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.2/antlr-master-3.2.jar
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grails unable to install plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715832/grails-unable-to-install-plugin)

Comment: tried that, I am getting the same thing

Comment: well it is [there](https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/) at least.  please update your question with the proper urls then

Comment: Done, can you see them now ?

Comment: i see no "tried" lines with that url.  you could also try with http instead of https.  proxy etc can be ruled out?

Comment: Ok I have edited my answer and now this is what happens! I do not understand why does it go through a loop ??!!?!!