# In trouble with Grails plugin installation

Tags: grails, plugins

For some reason I can't get the admin interface plugin of Grails to install.
I've added this line `compile ":admin-interface:0.7.1"` to BuildConfig.groovy. But I can't get it to work, I am assuming that some kind of network security of my company are blocking it as others plugins work perfectly fine (they are in cache).

What are my options as grails install-plugins is deprecated ?

Thank you so much in advance.

PS: Grails 2.2.4

Comment: can you rule out the wrong repo url?  see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28716326/3181392

Comment: That's the repo I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is a good way to do it. But I solved my issue by downloading the jar version of the plugin and put it in the lib folder of my project.