# Error | Failed to resolve dependencies in grails-app

Tags: gradle, groovy, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am facing this issue with Grails v2.0.3

Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):
grails version 2.0.3
java version 1.7
groovy version 2.4.17
OS LTS16.0.4

GRADLE_HOME, GRAILS_HOME, JAVA_HOME, GROOVY_HOME already configured.

Kindly help to check below issue

```
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
Host snapshots.repository.codehaus.org not found. url=http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/cookie/0.2/cookie-0.2.pom

module not found: org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2
==== grailsPlugins: tried
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
/home/cocktail/Documents/ibtapps/1-social_ui/lib/cookie-0.2.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/org.grails.plugins/cookie/ivy-0.2.xml
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/org.grails.plugins/cookie/jars/cookie-0.2.zip
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/org.grails.plugins/cookie/bundles/cookie-0.2.zip

==== grailsHome: tried
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/src/libs/google-analytics-2.3.3.xml
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#google-analytics;2.3.3!google-analytics.zip:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/src/libs/google-analytics-2.3.3.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#google-analytics;2.3.3!google-analytics.zip:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/plugins/google-analytics-2.3.3.zip
==== http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org: tried

\-- artifact batik#batik-svggen;1.6!batik-svggen.jar:
http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-batik-svggen/tags/RELEASE_1.6/grails-batik-svggen-1.6.jar
==== mavenCentral: tried
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/batik/batik-svggen/1.6/batik-svggen-1.6.pom
\-- artifact batik#batik-svggen;1.6!batik-svggen.jar:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/batik/batik-svggen/1.6/batik-svggen-1.6.jar
==== http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/signpost/: tried
http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/signpost/batik/batik-svggen/1.6/batik-svggen-1.6.pom
\-- artifact batik#batik-svggen;1.6!batik-svggen.jar:
http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/signpost/batik/batik-svggen/1.6/batik-svggen-1.6.jar
Host snapshots.repository.codehaus.org not found. url=http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/batik/batik-svg-dom/1.6/batik-svg-dom-1.6.pom
Host snapshots.repository.codehaus.org not found. url=http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/batik/batik-svg-dom/1.6/batik-svg-dom-1.6.jar
Host svn.codehaus.org not found. url=http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-batik-svg-dom/tags/RELEASE_1_6/batik-svg-dom-1.6.pom
Host svn.codehaus.org not found. url=http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-batik-svg-dom/tags/RELEASE_1_6/grails-batik-svg-dom-1.6.jar
module not found: batik#batik-svg-dom;1.6
==== grailsPlugins: tried
\-- artifact batik#batik-svg-dom;1.6!batik-svg-dom.jar:
/home/cocktail/Documents/ibtapps/1-social_ui/lib/batik-svg-dom-1.6.jar
==== grailsHome: tried
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/batik/batik-svg-dom/ivy-1.6.xml
\-- artifact batik#batik-svg-dom;1.6!batik-svg-dom.jar:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/batik/batik-svg-dom/jars/batik-svg-dom-1.6.jar
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/batik/batik-svg-dom/bundles/batik-svg-dom-1.6.jar

Host snapshots.repository.codehaus.org not found. url=http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/lesscss-resources/1.3.3/lesscss-resources-1.3.3.zip
Host svn.codehaus.org not found. url=http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-lesscss-resources/tags/RELEASE_1_3_3/lesscss-resources-1.3.3.pom
Host svn.codehaus.org not found. url=http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-lesscss-resources/tags/RELEASE_1_3_3/grails-lesscss-resources-1.3.3.zip
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/org.grails.plugins/lesscss-resources/bundles/lesscss-resources-1.3.3.zip
==== grailsHome: tried

SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/rhino/js/1.7R2/js-1.7R2.pom
SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/rhino/js/1.7R2/js-1.7R2.jar
SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/jquery/1.9.1/jquery-1.9.1.pom
SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/jquery/1.9.1/jquery-1.9.1.zip
SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/redis/1.3/redis-1.3.pom
SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/redis/1.3/redis-1.3.zip
SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/mail/1.0/mail-1.0.pom
SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/mail/1.0/mail-1.0.zip
SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-appinfo/1.0/spring-security-appinfo-1.0.pom
SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-appinfo/1.0/spring-security-appinfo-1.0.zip
SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.pom
SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/springcache/1.3.1/springcache-1.3.1.zip
SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/gmock/gmock/0.8.0/gmock-0.8.0.pom
SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/gmock/gmock/0.8.0/gmock-0.8.0.jar
SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.1/hamcrest-library-1.1.pom
SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.1/hamcrest-library-1.1.jar
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
module not found: org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2
==== grailsPlugins: tried
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
/home/cocktail/Documents/ibtapps/1-social_ui/lib/cookie-0.2.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/org.grails.plugins/cookie/ivy-0.2.xml
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/org.grails.plugins/cookie/jars/cookie-0.2.zip
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/org.grails.plugins/cookie/bundles/cookie-0.2.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/src/libs/cookie-0.2.xml
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/src/libs/cookie-0.2.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/dist/cookie-0.2.xml
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/dist/cookie-0.2.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
/home/cocktail/.grails/2.0.3/cached-installed-plugins/cookie-0.2.xml
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
/home/cocktail/.grails/2.0.3/cached-installed-plugins/cookie-0.2.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/plugins/cookie-0.2.zip
==== http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org: tried
http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/cookie/0.2/cookie-0.2.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/cookie/0.2/cookie-0.2.zip
==== grailsCentral: tried
http://plugins.grails.org/grails-cookie/tags/RELEASE_0.2/cookie-0.2.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
http://plugins.grails.org/grails-cookie/tags/RELEASE_0.2/grails-cookie-0.2.zip
==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins: tried
http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/cookie/0.2/cookie-0.2.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/cookie/0.2/cookie-0.2.zip
==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried
http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/cookie/0.2/cookie-0.2.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/cookie/0.2/cookie-0.2.zip
==== grailsCore: tried
http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-cookie/tags/RELEASE_0.2/cookie-0.2.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-cookie/tags/RELEASE_0.2/grails-cookie-0.2.zip
==== mavenCentral: tried
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/cookie/0.2/cookie-0.2.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/cookie/0.2/cookie-0.2.zip
==== http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/signpost/: tried
http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/signpost/org/grails/plugins/cookie/0.2/cookie-0.2.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/signpost/org/grails/plugins/cookie/0.2/cookie-0.2.zip
module not found: org.grails.plugins#geb;0.9.3
==== grailsPlugins: tried
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#geb;0.9.3!geb.zip:
/home/cocktail/Documents/ibtapps/1-social_ui/lib/geb-0.9.3.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/org.grails.plugins/geb/ivy-0.9.3.xml
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#geb;0.9.3!geb.zip:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/org.grails.plugins/geb/jars/geb-0.9.3.zip
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/org.grails.plugins/geb/bundles/geb-0.9.3.zip

/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/dist/js-1.7R2.jar
==== grailsHome: tried
/home/cocktail/.grails/2.0.3/cached-installed-plugins/js-1.7R2.xml
\-- artifact rhino#js;1.7R2!js.jar:
/home/cocktail/.grails/2.0.3/cached-installed-plugins/js-1.7R2.jar
==== grailsHome: tried
\-- artifact rhino#js;1.7R2!js.jar:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/plugins/js-1.7R2.jar
==== http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org: tried
http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/rhino/js/1.7R2/js-1.7R2.pom
\-- artifact rhino#js;1.7R2!js.jar:
http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/rhino/js/1.7R2/js-1.7R2.jar
==== grailsCentral: tried
http://plugins.grails.org/grails-js/tags/RELEASE_1.7R2/js-1.7R2.pom
\-- artifact rhino#js;1.7R2!js.jar:
http://plugins.grails.org/grails-js/tags/RELEASE_1.7R2/grails-js-1.7R2.jar
==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins: tried
http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/rhino/js/1.7R2/js-1.7R2.pom
\-- artifact rhino#js;1.7R2!js.jar:
http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/rhino/js/1.7R2/js-1.7R2.jar
==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried
http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/rhino/js/1.7R2/js-1.7R2.pom
\-- artifact rhino#js;1.7R2!js.jar:
http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/rhino/js/1.7R2/js-1.7R2.jar
==== grailsCore: tried
http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-js/tags/RELEASE_1.7R2/js-1.7R2.pom
\-- artifact rhino#js;1.7R2!js.jar:
http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-js/tags/RELEASE_1.7R2/grails-js-1.7R2.jar
==== mavenCentral: tried
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/rhino/js/1.7R2/js-1.7R2.pom
\-- artifact rhino#js;1.7R2!js.jar:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/rhino/js/1.7R2/js-1.7R2.jar
==== http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/signpost/: tried
http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/signpost/rhino/js/1.7R2/js-1.7R2.pom
\-- artifact rhino#js;1.7R2!js.jar:
http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/signpost/rhino/js/1.7R2/js-1.7R2.jar
module not found: org.grails.plugins#jquery;1.9.1
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#jquery;1.9.1!jquery.zip:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/org.grails.plugins/jquery/jars/jquery-1.9.1.zip
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/org.grails.plugins/jquery/bundles/jquery-1.9.1.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/src/libs/jquery-1.9.1.xml
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#jquery;1.9.1!jquery.zip:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/src/libs/jquery-1.9.1.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/dist/jquery-1.9.1.xml
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#jquery;1.9.1!jquery.zip:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/dist/jquery-1.9.1.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
/home/cocktail/.grails/2.0.3/cached-installed-plugins/jquery-1.9.1.xml
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#jquery;1.9.1!jquery.zip:
/home/cocktail/.grails/2.0.3/cached-installed-plugins/jquery-1.9.1.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#jquery;1.9.1!jquery.zip:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/plugins/jquery-1.9.1.zip
==== http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org: tried
http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/jquery/1.9.1/jquery-1.9.1.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#jquery;1.9.1!jquery.zip:
http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/jquery/1.9.1/jquery-1.9.1.zip
==== grailsCentral: tried
http://plugins.grails.org/grails-jquery/tags/RELEASE_1.9.1/jquery-1.9.1.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#jquery;1.9.1!jquery.zip:
http://plugins.grails.org/grails-jquery/tags/RELEASE_1.9.1/grails-jquery-1.9.1.zip
==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins: tried
http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/jquery/1.9.1/jquery-1.9.1.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#jquery;1.9.1!jquery.zip:
http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/jquery/1.9.1/jquery-1.9.1.zip
==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried
http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/jquery/1.9.1/jquery-1.9.1.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#jquery;1.9.1!jquery.zip:
http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/jquery/1.9.1/jquery-1.9.1.zip
==== grailsCore: tried
http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-jquery/tags/RELEASE_1.9.1/jquery-1.9.1.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#jquery;1.9.1!jquery.zip:
http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-jquery/tags/RELEASE_1.9.1/grails-jquery-1.9.1.zip
==== mavenCentral: tried
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/jquery/1.9.1/jquery-1.9.1.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#jquery;1.9.1!jquery.zip:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/jquery/1.9.1/jquery-1.9.1.zip
==== http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/signpost/: tried
http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/signpost/org/grails/plugins/jquery/1.9.1/jquery-1.9.1.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#jquery;1.9.1!jquery.zip:
http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/signpost/org/grails/plugins/jquery/1.9.1/jquery-1.9.1.zip
module not found: org.grails.plugins#redis;1.3
==== grailsPlugins: tried
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#redis;1.3!redis.zip:
/home/cocktail/Documents/ibtapps/1-social_ui/lib/redis-1.3.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/org.grails.plugins/redis/ivy-1.3.xml
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#redis;1.3!redis.zip:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/org.grails.plugins/redis/jars/redis-1.3.zip
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/org.grails.plugins/redis/bundles/redis-1.3.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/src/libs/redis-1.3.xml
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#redis;1.3!redis.zip:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/src/libs/redis-1.3.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/dist/redis-1.3.xml
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#redis;1.3!redis.zip:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/dist/redis-1.3.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
/home/cocktail/.grails/2.0.3/cached-installed-plugins/redis-1.3.xml
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#redis;1.3!redis.zip:
/home/cocktail/.grails/2.0.3/cached-installed-plugins/redis-1.3.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#redis;1.3!redis.zip:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/plugins/redis-1.3.zip
==== http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org: tried
http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/redis/1.3/redis-1.3.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#redis;1.3!redis.zip:
http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/redis/1.3/redis-1.3.zip
==== grailsCentral: tried
http://plugins.grails.org/grails-redis/tags/RELEASE_1.3/redis-1.3.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#redis;1.3!redis.zip:
http://plugins.grails.org/grails-redis/tags/RELEASE_1.3/grails-redis-1.3.zip
==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins: tried
http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/redis/1.3/redis-1.3.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#redis;1.3!redis.zip:
http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/redis/1.3/redis-1.3.zip
==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried
http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/redis/1.3/redis-1.3.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#redis;1.3!redis.zip:
http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/redis/1.3/redis-1.3.zip
==== grailsCore: tried
http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-redis/tags/RELEASE_1.3/redis-1.3.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#redis;1.3!redis.zip:
http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-redis/tags/RELEASE_1.3/grails-redis-1.3.zip
==== mavenCentral: tried
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/redis/1.3/redis-1.3.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#redis;1.3!redis.zip:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/redis/1.3/redis-1.3.zip
==== http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/signpost/: tried
http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/signpost/org/grails/plugins/redis/1.3/redis-1.3.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#redis;1.3!redis.zip:
http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/signpost/org/grails/plugins/redis/1.3/redis-1.3.zip

==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins: tried
http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/springcache/1.3.1/springcache-1.3.1.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#springcache;1.3.1!springcache.zip:
http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/springcache/1.3.1/springcache-1.3.1.zip
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2: not found
:: org.grails.plugins#geb;0.9.3: not found
:: org.grails.plugins#google-analytics;2.3.3: not found
:: org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.5.2: not found
:: redis.clients#jedis;2.1.0: not found
:: org.apache.poi#poi-ooxml;3.9: not found
:: org.apache.poi#poi-excelant;3.9: not found
:: org.apache.poi#poi-scratchpad;3.9: not found
:: batik#batik-xml;1.6: not found
:: batik#batik-transcoder;1.6: not found
:: batik#batik-util;1.6: not found
:: batik#batik-svggen;1.6: not found
:: batik#batik-svg-dom;1.6: not found
:: batik#batik-dom;1.6: not found
:: batik#batik-slideshow;1.6: not found
:: com.google.code.gson#gson;1.4: not found
:: rhino#js;1.7R2: not found
:: org.grails.plugins#jquery;1.9.1: not found
:: org.grails.plugins#redis;1.3: not found
:: org.grails.plugins#mail;1.0: not found
:: org.grails.plugins#spring-security-appinfo;1.0: not found
:: org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core;1.2.7.3: not found
:: org.grails.plugins#lesscss-resources;1.3.3: not found
:: org.grails.plugins#famfamfam;1.0.1: not found
:: org.grails.plugins#spring-security-ui;0.2: not found
:: org.grails.plugins#springcache;1.3.1: not found
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
module not found: org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2
==== grailsPlugins: tried
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
/home/cocktail/Documents/ibtapps/1-social_ui/lib/cookie-0.2.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/org.grails.plugins/cookie/ivy-0.2.xml
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/org.grails.plugins/cookie/jars/cookie-0.2.zip
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/org.grails.plugins/cookie/bundles/cookie-0.2.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/src/libs/cookie-0.2.xml
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/src/libs/cookie-0.2.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/dist/cookie-0.2.xml
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/dist/cookie-0.2.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
/home/cocktail/.grails/2.0.3/cached-installed-plugins/cookie-0.2.xml
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
/home/cocktail/.grails/2.0.3/cached-installed-plugins/cookie-0.2.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/plugins/cookie-0.2.zip
==== http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org: tried
http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/cookie/0.2/cookie-0.2.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/cookie/0.2/cookie-0.2.zip
==== grailsCentral: tried
==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried
http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/cookie/0.2/cookie-0.2.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/cookie/0.2/cookie-0.2.zip
==== grailsCore: tried
http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-cookie/tags/RELEASE_0.2/cookie-0.2.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-cookie/tags/RELEASE_0.2/grails-cookie-0.2.zip
==== mavenCentral: tried
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/cookie/0.2/cookie-0.2.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/cookie/0.2/cookie-0.2.zip
==== http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/signpost/: tried
http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/signpost/org/grails/plugins/cookie/0.2/cookie-0.2.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2!cookie.zip:
http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/signpost/org/grails/plugins/cookie/0.2/cookie-0.2.zip
module not found: org.grails.plugins#geb;0.9.3
==== grailsPlugins: tried
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#geb;0.9.3!geb.zip:
/home/cocktail/Documents/ibtapps/1-social_ui/lib/geb-0.9.3.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/org.grails.plugins/geb/ivy-0.9.3.xml
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#geb;0.9.3!geb.zip:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/org.grails.plugins/geb/jars/geb-0.9.3.zip
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/org.grails.plugins/geb/bundles/geb-0.9.3.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/src/libs/geb-0.9.3.xml
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#geb;0.9.3!geb.zip:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/src/libs/geb-0.9.3.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#geb;0.9.3!geb.zip:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/plugins/geb-0.9.3.zip
==== http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org: tried
http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/geb/0.9.3/geb-0.9.3.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#geb;0.9.3!geb.zip:
http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/geb/0.9.3/geb-0.9.3.zip
==== grailsCentral: tried
==== grailsCore: tried
http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-geb/tags/RELEASE_0.9.3/geb-0.9.3.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#geb;0.9.3!geb.zip:
http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-geb/tags/RELEASE_0.9.3/grails-geb-0.9.3.zip
==== mavenCentral: tried
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/geb/0.9.3/geb-0.9.3.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#geb;0.9.3!geb.zip:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/geb/0.9.3/geb-0.9.3.zip
==== http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/signpost/: tried
http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/signpost/org/grails/plugins/geb/0.9.3/geb-0.9.3.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#geb;0.9.3!geb.zip:
http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/signpost/org/grails/plugins/geb/0.9.3/geb-0.9.3.zip
module not found: org.grails.plugins#google-analytics;2.3.3
==== grailsPlugins: tried
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#google-analytics;2.3.3!google-analytics.zip:
/home/cocktail/Documents/ibtapps/1-social_ui/lib/google-analytics-2.3.3.zip
==== grailsHome: tried
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/org.grails.plugins/google-analytics/ivy-2.3.3.xml
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#google-analytics;2.3.3!google-analytics.zip:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/org.grails.plugins/google-analytics/jars/google-analytics-2.3.3.zip
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/lib/org.grails.plugins/google-analytics/bundles/google-analytics-2.3.3.zip

==== grailsHome: tried
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#google-analytics;2.3.3!google-analytics.zip:
/home/cocktail/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.0.3/plugins/google-analytics-2.3.3.zip
==== http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org: tried
http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/google-analytics/2.3.3/google-analytics-2.3.3.pom
\-- artifact org.grails.plugins#google-analytics;2.3.3!google-analytics.zip:
http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/google-analytics/2.3.3/google-analytics-2.3.3.zip
==== grailsCentral: tried
http://plugins.grails.org/grails-google-analytics/tags/RELEASE_2.3.3/google-analytics-2.3.3.pom

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: org.grails.plugins#cookie;0.2: not found
:: org.grails.plugins#geb;0.9.3: not found
:: org.grails.plugins#google-analytics;2.3.3: not found
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Error |
Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.grails.plugins:cookie:0.2
- org.grails.plugins:geb:0.9.3
- org.grails.plugins:google-analytics:2.3.3

Trying to run in ubuntu server with below configuration,
grails version 2.0.3
java version 1.7
groovy version 2.4.17
OS LTS16.0.4
```

Comment: Grails 2.0.3 is 11 years old. Codehaus (where it's looking for dependencies) shut down almost 8 years ago.

Comment: Yes, grails 2.0.3 is very old but, still, one product using this version, already deployed application working fine but the new setup having the above issues.

Comment: You could try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715832/grails-unable-to-install-plugin