# Grails Dependency not resolving in version 2.2.5

Tags: maven, grails, grails-plugin, ivy, maven-central

After removing ivy cache under .grails folder now any of my application is working(Even newly created) because of unable to resolve dependency issue in Grails 2.2.5 version.

i am getting below logs in compilation

```
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        :: org.grails.plugins#cache;1.0.1: not found
        :: org.grails.plugins#rendering;0.4.4: not found
        :: org.grails.plugins#ckeditor;3.6.6.1.0: not found
        :: org.grails.plugins#rest-client-builder;1.0.2: not found
        :: org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core;1.2.7.3: not found
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.grails.plugins:cache:1.0.1
- org.grails.plugins:rendering:0.4.4
- org.grails.plugins:ckeditor:3.6.6.1.0
- org.grails.plugins:rest-client-builder:1.0.2
- org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:1.2.7.3
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grails unable to install plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715832/grails-unable-to-install-plugin)

Comment: @Zoidberg: This is the different case my application was working fine earlier and now the issue is plugins are not downloading at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some problems with older Grails versions, you have to update your repository path.

See my answer at: [Grails Url shortener plugin not getting installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28698371/grails-url-shortener-plugin-not-getting-installed/28699638#28699638) :

> Please use
>
> ```
> mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"
> ```
>
> As a repository definition.

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-central-repo-seemingly-missing-plugin-versions-td4658720.html